# How to ensure button is clicked even moving position

Tags: javascript, html, events

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fboubvs/5/

```
<input id="losefocus">
<div id="validationMessage">Text disappears when "valid"</div>
<div>
<button>Next</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

    $('button').on('click', function(){
        alert('I was clicked');
    });

    $('#losefocus').on('change', function(){
        $('#validationMessage').hide();
    });
});
```

I have a text input in a state of "error" with a validation message below.

I type something correct and while focus is still on the text button I click a button next that is located under the input and the validation message.

If I click low on the button it will not trigger a click, since the removal of the message moves the button up as well.

What are the workarounds to this? One approach I have thought of is to do the change event slightly async so that the button is clicked first, then the value is updated and then the message removed.

This however will cause any reading of the value of the input done in the click handler for the button to use the previous value of the input.

Also: pay attention to the button: it seems to get activated, visually it get a "pressed" or "active" look, but the click event is not fired.

Comment: I am not seeing any problem with clicking the button after the text was removed. What browser are you having trouble in?

Comment: it's if you enter some text, leave the focus in the text box, then click on the very bottom of the button, the validation message disappears, the screen reflows, the button moves, you lose the click.

Comment: Chrome 36. Remember it's important to type new text, don't make the input loose focus and click on the bottom of the button.

Comment: One option is to do validation on keydown with a throttle.. that way the screen reflows when the user is typing. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2fboubvs/11/)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use visibility:hidden on the message, then the area for the text is left without reflowing.

```
    $('#validationMessage').css("visibility","hidden");
```

Comment: Yes I know, and I should have mentioned that this is not a desired solution. The error messages might be more than one line. And what leaves too much whitespace.

Comment: I've always found that reflowing on the fly isn't very nice though. Consider putting your error next to the box, the button next to the box etc. If you must do on the fly validation which hides bits of the DOM, maybe consider the key events as they'll get fired sooner?